# @FetchRequest crashes preview

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to load items from the database into a list, it works fine on device and simulator but Preview will always crash with the following message:

"Cannot preview in this file — Connection interrupted: send message to agent"

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: ChildProfile.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var children: FetchedResults<ChildProfile>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Children")) {
                    ForEach(children, id: \.id) { child in
                        ChildRow(child: child)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    
    static var previews: some View {
        let defaultChild = ChildProfile(context: moc)
        defaultChild.id = UUID()
        defaultChild.name = "Dale"
        return SettingsView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
    }
}
```

Looking at the diagnostics of thew preview crash it shows:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516
> "“ChildProfile+CoreDataClass.swift” couldn’t be linked to
> “Intermediates” because an item with the same name already exists."
> UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BedtimeClock-hehxrojiiepyadgitseedusiyozd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Project
> One/Intermediates.noindex/Project
> One.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project
> One.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/ChildProfile+CoreDataClass.swift,
> NSUserStringVariant=(
>  >     Link > ),
> NSDestinationFilePath=/var/folders/dp/hztzhf572q26jwx6vb9nqpw0000gn/T/previews-diagnostics-20200713-200707/Intermediates/ChildProfile+CoreDataClass.swift,
> NSFilePath=/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bedtime_Clock-hehxrojiiepyadgitseedusiyozd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Project
> One/Intermediates.noindex/Project
> One.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project
> One.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/ChildProfile+CoreDataClass.swift,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb78a150620 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=17 "File exists"}}

I can successfully preview ChildRow(), using the same preview code. So is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Clean > close Xcode > Delete Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData > open Xcode > Rebuild

Comment: @Asperi no dice. I'd tried that along with deleting the previews simulator data. Still get the same error.